# What does this sentence with いつ mean?

Tags: questions, interrogatives

I can't understand the last sentence in this video: [世にも奇妙な物語 《戦争はなかった》](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KALbSuGUDhQ). I think this is what he's saying, starting at 17:41:

> しかし歴史というのはもともと活字と映像の中しか残らない、実に頼りないものです。奇妙な力によってそれが歪められた時、あなたの身にもいつこのような恐怖が降りかからないとも限りません。

Maybe I misheard, but if this is correct, what does the last sentence mean? The いつ is really throwing me off, since it's not いつも or いつか and the sentence isn't a question. If いつ wasn't there, I think it would (basically) mean "this kind of thing could happen to you, too."

Comment: the time when the sentence comes up in the video would be very helpful

Comment: I added the time to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a *strange* mixture of the ～とも/とは限らない construction and the [interrogative + とも + ない](https://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%EF%BC%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%AB-tomonaku-tomonashini.html) construction. Although perfectly understandable, I feel this sentence is not well-formed. It should have been either of:

- あなたの身にも、いつ**か**このような恐怖が降りかからないとも限りません。
- あなたの身にも、いつこのような恐怖が降りかかるとも知れません。

Here are some examples of `interrogative + とも + 知れない/分からない` from BCCWJ:

> - ともあれ一行は、どことも知れぬ場所を進む。
> - いつやむとも知れないつめたい雨が、野と山とそして村村をおし包んで降りつづける。
> - 女房のところにあちこちのどこの誰とも知れない男たちが通っているとのこと。
> - いつ突然変異を起こして人から人への感染が起きるとも知れない現状にある。
> - 3人の女優はまたいつくるとも分からない出番に備えて稽古を続けていく。